# Stanford NLP pos-tagger model REQUIREMENTS

Tags: stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I have made a basic application where I use Stanford Parser through OpenIE Lib and when the StanfordCoreNLP is initialized with the specified properties it stops as pos (pos-tagger). I do think all the required models are included so not sure why the process is unable to find the model data.

```
Properties props = new Properties();       
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
Annotation doc = new Annotation(testString);
pipeline.annotate(doc);
for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class))
{
  Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
  for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {              
    System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
       triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
       triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
       triple.objectLemmaGloss());
  }
}
```

The includes are

```
stanford-parser.jar
stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar
stanford-openie.jar
stanford-openie-models.jar
JDK1.8
```

Stack-trace when the StanfordCoreNLP class is initiated.

```
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.2 sec].
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REQUIREMENTS
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.requires(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:169)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:362)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:131)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:127)
    at org.sjdp.q2sm.GUI.extractTriplets(GUI.java:373)
    at org.sjdp.q2sm.GUI.processSPARQL(GUI.java:353)
    at org.sjdp.q2sm.GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:153)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a class incompatibility bug from including both the parser and the OpenIE system at the same time. It'll be fixed in the next release (3.5.3) when everything syncs up again, but since OpenIE didn't exist at the 3.5.2 release the code in that jar is a bit "ahead" of the parser.

The easiest way to run the two at the same time is to run from the Github version of [CoreNLP](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP). The command `ant jar` should create a jar file which contains both the parser and the OpenIE system. The [most recent models](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar) (warning: large download) should have both the parser and OpenIE models.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works now only complaining that the dcoref model cannot be found when using the 80mb model lib. The Model is a little big but it should not get in the way.

Comment: The coref models should not be loaded unless you pass in the flag `-resolve_coref`. In that case, you have to use the OpenIE system through the CoreNLP distribution, which means using the GitHub version of CoreNLP (except that coref is currently broken in HEAD; use [this commit](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/7ffd9ba389b792175791d502f99d619782819039) instead) and the associated most recent models.